# Why is a PNG file often larger without transparency?

Tags: web, png, transparency, frontend, photoshop

Often when I am saving a PNG-24 file with transparent areas for web in Photoshop, the file size gets larger when I deselect the transparency option.

[image]

On the file I was just working on, the file size with transparency was 45.28k, but without transparency it was 53.71k, which is not an insignificant difference.

**Can anyone explain this behaviour?**

Comment: Not unless you post a sample file that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: I'm asking about why this could happen in general. I'm not interested in my  individual use case alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplified answer: PNGs save purely transparent pixels as a binary value, whereas they save values with color using the equivalent of an RGB or RGBA value (which takes much more space than one bit).

In actuality, pixels that are not purely transparent are grouped in chunks, which are analyzed for their color requirements and use the minimum applicable option for color depth in order to save space pre-compression. Before that happens, though, pixels are first examined to see if they are purely transparent in order to ensure both that they're represented accordingly and that other pixels do not become transparent in error. You can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Technical_details).

Comment: The  PNG format allows two kinds of transparency: a single value in a look-up table (close to GIFs transparency) or as a full-blown 8- or 16-bit deep separate channel. You can't tell from the OP's scant information which gets used.

Comment: Yeah, the answer was meant to be only a general intuition. The binary value is the look-up I thought (am I mistaken?), and the alternative is based off the color palette assigned to that chunk (you're right- 8 or 16 bit deep if it's transparent, but also allowing 1, 2, and 4 bit depth if lacking transparency and indexed palette or grayscale)